# Creating scopes based on multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I'm trying to create a scope that's a little out of the ordinary.  I've got an app that deals with websites.  There's a model called "sites", which has_many pages.  The sites model has a column called homepage.  The list of pages for each site contains the homepage and additional pages (about, pricing, whatever).

I'd like to create two scopes for the pages model.  One identifies the homepage and the other identifies all the additional pages.  I was thinking of something like this.

```
my_homepage =  Site.find_by_id(self.site_id).homepage
scope :homepage, where(url: my_homepage) 
scope :additional_pages, where(url != my_homepage)
```

Unfortunately, these don't work.  In fact, when I try to play with them in console, I can't.  I get this error.

```
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
scope :homepage, joins(:sites).where("sites.homepage = pages.url") 
scope :additional_pages, joins(:sites).where("sites.homepage <> pages.url")
```

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen a scope done like that.  I adjusted your code to say "joints(:site)" (singular) and it works great.  One question: I noticed that among my additional_pages, I've got robots.txt files appearing.  I want to exclude those, but I'm not sure how.  I appended ` .where("'robots.txt' <> pages.url[-10,10]")` to the additional_pages method, but no luck.  Any suggestions? (I can ask in another StackOverflow post, if you like.)

Comment: Yes it's better to create another question. (And validate an up my answer :) )

Comment: Follow up question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694325/multiple-model-scope-with-multiple-where-statements