# Multiple Model Scope with Multiple Where Statements

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I've got an app that deals with websites. There's a model called "sites", which has_many pages. The sites model has a column called homepage. The list of pages for each site contains the homepage and additional pages (about, pricing, whatever).

In this post: 
[Creating scopes based on multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693310/creating-scopes-based-on-multiple-models/11693380#11693380), I was able to figure out how to scope the pages model so I could separate the homepage from the additional pages.  But I need to modify my the scope further because I noticed that among my additional_pages, I've got robots.txt files appearing. I want to exclude those, but I'm not sure how. I appended this:

```
.where("'robots.txt' <> pages.url[-10,10]")
```

but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this : `.where("pages.url NOT LIKE '%robots.txt'")`

Comment: Terrific.  That works perfectly!  Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Approuve this answer if you're happy!"

Comment: Sorry.  SO was making me wait to approve and then I completely forgot about it.